# Trigger specific mouse event on another element

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, mousewheel

I have a web application containing an image on which a `mousewheel` event is caught in order to zoom the image precisely on the point where the cursor is.

On top of this image, I display a custom tooltip which is just a div containing text. When I `mousewheel` on the tooltip, the image is not zoomed.

I tried to bind the image `mousewheel` event on the tooltip but then, the `offsetX` and `offsetY` of the event correspond to the cursor position relative to the tooltip and not relative to the image.

How can I:

- <s>either get the *image* `offsetX` and `offsetY`, even when the cursor is over the tooltip? or</s>
- prevent the tooltip to catch the mousewheel event before the image?

**EDIT:**
Actually, Before, I could select the tooltip by clicking on it; but by adding the CSS style `'pointer-events:none'` (suggested by *Aramil Rey*), the `click` event has no effects (obviously).

Therefore, how can I:

- prevent the tooltip to catch the `mousewheel` event before the image?
- **and still** let the tooltip catch the `click` event?

Answer (score 0):

I assume currently you are getting `offsetX` and `offsetY` from `event.target`. Set an ID to the image and replace `event.target` with `$("#imageID")[0]`. Better yet, jquery provides an [offset function](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

```
var image = $('#image');

image.add('.tooltip').bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     var offset = image.offset();
     var mouseX = event.pageX - offset.left;
     var mouseY = event.pageY - offset.top;

     // zoom stuff
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, I changed a little bit the question. Could you have a look please :-).

Comment: @Jav: editted. To reiterate, this code will work because it uses an absolute reference to your image rather than a relative one via event.target.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using CSS: `pointer-events:none;` on the tooltip?

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ysLprvf7/1/)

Try hovering on the red div, and you will notice that it won't trigger its attached event, and intead it will trigger yellow div on mouseeenter event if you enter that div, even if your cursor is over the red div.

```js
$('.asd').on('mouseenter', function() {
    alert('asd');
});

$('.ddaa').on('mouseenter', function() {
    alert('ddaa');
});
```

```css
.ddaa {
    padding-top: 15px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.asd {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    pointer-events:none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    top: 5px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ddaa">
</div>
<div class="asd">
</div>
```

Comment: "Note that preventing an element from being the target of mouse events by using pointer-events does not necessarily mean that mouse event listeners on that element cannot or will not be triggered." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Notes

Comment: it really is what I wanted ! : the style `'pointer-events:none'`. Thank you :-)

Comment: what if I would like to allow a `click` event on the tooltip and not the `mousewheel` events ?